# Debian, cmake, connot compile c++ program, missing config cmake file

Tags: c++, cmake, debian

Trying to compile [dot11decrypt](https://github.com/mfontanini/dot11decrypt) on debian, installed `apt-get install libtins4.0` and `apt-get install libtins-dev`, but `cmake ..` can't find package libtins, heres the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (FIND_PACKAGE):
By not providing "Findlibtins.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libtins", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libtins" with any
of the following names:

libtinsConfig.cmake
libtins-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "libtins" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"libtins_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"libtins" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/dot11decrypt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

cat:dot11decrypt/CMakeLists.txt

```
1. CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.1)
2. PROJECT(dot11decrypt)
3. 
4. FIND_PACKAGE(libtins REQUIRED)
5.
6. SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
7.
8. ADD_EXECUTABLE(dot11decrypt dot11decrypt.cpp)
9. TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(dot11decrypt ${LIBTINS_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

`find / -name Findlibtins.cmake` or libtinsConfig.cmake brings no result.

I found those files on internet but still no success, i think i have to install something but don't know what.

Comment: The packet `libtins-dev` from the Debian repository [misses](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/amd64/libtins-dev/filelist) the script `libtinsConfig.cmake`. You need to build and install libtins from sources.

Comment: Thanks for input, i will try to compile tins from sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compile from source... `find_package` is a very flexible configuration point! You'll just need to provide your own find module that is sufficient for the build. Fortunately, this is very simple. Here's what I did:

```
$ https://github.com/mfontanini/dot11decrypt
$ cd dot11decrypt
$ mkdir _patches
$ vim _patches/Findlibtins.cmake
$ cat _patches/Findlibtins.cmake 
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBTINS REQUIRED libtins)
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$PWD/_patches
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for module 'libtins'
--   Found libtins, version 4.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/dot11decrypt/build
$ cmake --build build/
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dot11decrypt.dir/dot11decrypt.cpp.o
/home/alex/test/dot11decrypt/dot11decrypt.cpp: In function ‘void decrypt_traffic(unique_fd, const string&, decrypter_tuple)’:
/home/alex/test/dot11decrypt/dot11decrypt.cpp:333:39: warning: ‘Tins::Sniffer::Sniffer(const string&, unsigned int, bool, const string&, bool)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  333 |     Sniffer sniffer(iface, 2500, false);
      |                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/tins/dns.h:38,
                 from /usr/include/tins/tins.h:33,
                 from /home/alex/test/dot11decrypt/dot11decrypt.cpp:25:
/usr/include/tins/sniffer.h:369:5: note: declared here
  369 |     TINS_DEPRECATED(Sniffer(const std::string& device, unsigned max_packet_size,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable dot11decrypt
[100%] Built target dot11decrypt
```

The key here is to create a minimal Find module. This is just two lines on my system since it isn't meant to be reusable...

```
# _patches/Findlibtins.cmake
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(LIBTINS REQUIRED libtins)
```

This just delegates the responsibility of setting the `LIBTINS_LIBRARIES` to `pkg-config`. To connect this find module to the build, I just set `-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$PWD/_patches` at the CMake configure command line.

Also, you should *definitely* open a bug report with the `dot11decrypt` author about their broken and outdated build. Notice the strongly worded deprecation warning in the logs I posted.

Comment: Nice, thanks for this solution. But for now i already uninstalled libtins4.0 and libtins-dev and compiled libtins from source.

Answer (score 2):

I went with Tsyvarev solution.

```
# installing missing dependencies for libtins
apt-get install libpcap-dev libssl-dev cmake
# installing libtins
git clone https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins.git
cd libtins
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
checkinstall
```

Now cmake will reach dot11decrypt missing files.

```
# installing dot11decrypt
git clone https://github.com/mfontanini/dot11decrypt.git
cd dot11decrypt/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make
```

Now you should have dot11decrypt executable.

If i would have to do it again i would try Alex Reinking solution first.